# Find Arithmetic Brownian Motion's transition density

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic

Consider the following stochastic differential equation, an Arithmetic Brownian Motion: () =   +  () . Find its solution, integrating from t to T, then find its transition density. Hint: using Itô, one would utilize the substitution  = (). However doing so is equivalent to simply integrating the SDE directly anyways.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
   S(T) - S(t) := \int_t^T dS(s) = r(T-t) + \sigma (W(T) - W(t))
\end{align}

Since $W(T) - W(t) \sim N(0, T-t)$, we have $S(T) \sim N\left(S(t) + r(T-t),\sigma^2(T-t) \right)$.